# Firebase: analyze "post score" events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Firebase provides a default event type for [posting game scores](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317494?hl=en). It includes parameters for the game level, character and score that was posted. However, viewing this event in the Firebase analytics console I can't see the level/character/score data anywhere, though I can see the total number of "post score" events.

How can I analyze e.g. the distribution of scores, or the average level achieved per game, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all predefined event params are reflected in reports. You have a couple of options for further analysis: you can create audiences with filters based on the param values you're interested in, or you can use BigQuery for more in-depth analysis of your data.
EDIT: You can now set up [custom parameter reporting](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304).