# Firebase ITEM_NAME not visible in Analytics dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to see which parts of my app are most used, for this I have added a `logEvent` like this:

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "action");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "screen_a");
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event,VIEW_ITEM, bundle);
```

The events get logged and I can see in my Dashboard under Events section a `view_item` entry with the Count, however, when I enter it, I can see the counts, meaning values, but I can't see any values like "screen_a" or "screen_b"...

Since these are not custom events, shouldn't the values be available in the dashboard?

Comment: This question has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721294/firebase-analyze-post-score-events/43811496#43811496).

Answer (score 6):

I got the same question as you. By asking email to firebase team, they replied the exact method to watch the log of item_name. Below are the example, I logged an ITEM_NAME "action_getProVersion" with ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE event:

1. log event in your codes: (You have done this)

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

   //bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, itemId);
   bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "action_getProVersion");
   //bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
   mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE, bundle);
2. On the firebase event screen, press on the right side,for event "Edit parameter reporting", then add "item_name" and save. (it looks you haven't done this)
   [image]
3. After a while, let it log from users event. You will see the events logged with parameter "ITEM_NAME" as the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the correct answer. This is a bit super cumbersome. Why would you set up the same thing twice, once in the SDK by adding the parameter to the bundle, and then in the dashboard. Imagine you have to do configure that for n events manually in the dashboard. Google Analytics SDK did not require this and just took the parameters as the got in.

Comment: I do not know why Firebase needs to configure the item_name for showing the data.
One reason may be they want to limit the number of item_name to be shown. Before they limited 10 item_name of text to be shown, but now I find it can be added more.

Comment: How would I display that in the Google Analytics Analysis hub? I added "Item Name" to the "Columns" dimension, but all events have `(not set)` for the item name. In Firebase console I see the `item name` table correctly, but in Google Analytics it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It needs to catch the new events to show "Item Name". The old events which were collected before may be just the same without "Item Name". If you mean Firebase can see it and Analytics can't, you may feedback Analytics to clarify that.

Comment: It is missing also for new events. I opened a ticket with Analytics, let’s see what they say.

Comment: this seems not to work anymore. In the same menu, instead of "Edit parameter reporting" option, it displays only "Mark as NPA"

Answer (score 1):

To Log event in firebase use the code below:

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, getString(R.string.title_activity_quotes));
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "ShareButton");
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

[Add item_name in event page of firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emGbh.png)

Then You can debug from android studio or wait sometime to occur the event, then check in the select_content event in firebase

[firebase select-content streamview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9jj.png)